# magento2 check exit email customer registed

Tags: magento2.3

I want to check the email customer registed. I have file save.php and i have

> $email = ab@gmail.com;

```
public function checkExistEmail($email){
    $customerCheckEmail->setWebsiteId(1);
    $customerCheckEmail = $this->_customerFactory->loadByEmail($email);

    if($customerCheckEmail->getId()){
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Email Registed!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following way ..

```
<?php
namespace Path\To\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class EmailCheck {
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ) {
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function emailExistOrNot(): bool
    {
        $email = "ab@gmail.com";
        $websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
        $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($email, $websiteId);
        return $isEmailNotExists;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it working